# Mobile menu toggle issue (onclick only works on outer container, not button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, toggle

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/GtC6x/10/ (animated dynamic height)

Now, you can click on both the button and the whole red area to toggle. I only want the purple area to be the one that toggles, with this markup structure.

`$('.nav-container').on('click', function() {`

Should be

`$('.nav-toggle').on('click', function() {`

But then it breaks. What do I need to change in the code? As a js newbie I've been staring at this code for a while but have failed to see where/why the toggle has to sit on the outer container to work.

```
$('.nav-container').on('click', function() {
    slide($('.nav-wrap .nav', this));
});

function slide(content) {
    var wrapper = content.parent();
    var contentHeight = content.outerHeight(true);
    var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();

    wrapper.toggleClass('expand');
    if (wrapper.hasClass('expand')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        wrapper.addClass('transition').css('height', contentHeight);
    }, 10);
}
else {
    setTimeout(function() {
        wrapper.css('height', wrapperHeight);
        setTimeout(function() {
        wrapper.addClass('transition').css('height', 0);
        }, 10);
    }, 10);
}

wrapper.one('transitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd transitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd', function() {
    if(wrapper.hasClass('open')) {
        wrapper.removeClass('transition').css('height', 'auto');
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing your function to `.nav-toggle` your `this` was no longer targeting the `container` instead it was your `nav-toggle` to get the same functionality we needed to get the parent of your `nav-toggle` which is the `nav-container`.

```
$('.nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    slide($('.nav-wrap .nav', $(this).parent()));
});
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GtC6x/12/

Comment: Ah, now I get it at last. Thanks for that explanation and solution. Perfect!